# How do I customize the colors used by 'jq -C'?

Tags: jq

How do I specify colors other than the defaults used for [`jq --color-output`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Invokingjq)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Support for the [`JQ_COLORS` environment variable](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Colors) was added to the development version on April 29, 2017 (that is, *after* the release of jq 1.5), with the following documentation:

> To configure alternative colors just set the `JQ_COLORS`
> environment variable to colon-delimited list of partial terminal
> escape sequences like `"1;31"`, in this order:
>
> ```
> - color for `null`
> - color for `false`
> - color for `true`
> - color for numbers
> - color for strings
> - color for arrays
> - color for objects
> ```
>
> The default color scheme is the same as setting
> `"JQ_COLORS=1;30:0;39:0;39:0;39:0;32:1;39:1;39"`.
>
> This is not a manual for VT100/ANSI escapes.  However, each of
> these color specifications should consist of two numbers separated
> by a semi-colon, where the first number is one of these:
>
> ```
> - 1 (bright)
> - 2 (dim)
> - 4 (underscore)
> - 5 (blink)
> - 7 (reverse)
> - 8 (hidden)
> ```
>
> and the second is one of these:
>
> ```
> - 30 (black)
> - 31 (red)
> - 32 (green)
> - 33 (yellow)
> - 34 (blue)
> - 35 (magenta)
> - 36 (cyan)
> - 37 (white)
> ```

Comment: Version 1.5 seems to ignore this.

Comment: And is there no way to change the color of a key, that's actually all I'm interested in changing.

Comment: Homebrew is installing 1.5. Is there a later version I should be using?

Comment: @orome - jq 1.5 is (alas) the most recent "official" version.  With homebrew, you could try: `brew install --HEAD jq`; see also https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation

Comment: Is there a way to change the color of a key? That's the only part that's really necessary.

Comment: The color of keys is governed by the "color for objects".  If that is not sufficient, you might like to try the npm package jsome

Comment: I believe you want `FIELD_COLOR`, which is set in [src/jv_print.c line 35](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/6d89e297febdbcbad4ecf201e56fc8ec99f67137/src/jv_print.c#L35).

Comment: terminal-colors.d(5): "The terminal-colors.d functionality is currently supported by all util-linux utilities which provides colorized output." ― false statement?

Comment: TLDR If you got here because you're using a dark color theme and your `null` values are invisible: Set this environment variable to switch your black bold invisible `null` to a red non-bold one: `export JQ_COLORS='0;31:0;39:0;39:0;39:0;32:1;39:1;39'` - The part affecting this is the initial characters `0;31` which translates to `non-bold;red`. change `0;` to `1;` for boldness, change `31` to `37` to make it white and non intrusive.

Comment: There is an open pull request to support changing the colour of object keys, however it has yet to be merged after two years. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1791

Comment: @Jonathan Holvey thanks for the link. For anyone else who wants to subscribe so they notifications once a PR gets merged... there's also [issue 1739](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1739) (mentioned in the link Jonathan posted) and an alternate [pull request 1977](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1977) which would fix the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since @peak's [answer in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51341700/3547184), the jqlang project has merged [jqlang/jq#2703](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2703) which now provides a way to change the color of object *keys* by appending an additional number set. Example:

```bash
# tested with jq-1.7
export JQ_COLORS="2;33:2;33:0;33:0;36:1;32:0;35:1;35:2;34"
```

The above example sets:

- null: dim yellow
- false: dim yellow
- true: yellow
- numbers: cyan
- strings: bright green
- arrays: magenta
- objects: bright magenta
- object *keys*: dim blue

See the [jq v1.7 manual on colors](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.7/#colors) for more details.